# Is there a way to programmatically set a specific terminal font upon application start up?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, game-development

I am working on a text-based adventure game written in Java and am wondering if there's a way to enforce the use of a certain terminal font in order to ensure that certain characters are spaced in a consistent way for "drawing" things like the level map and UI elements.

From some research here on SO I see that System.out isn't capable of using a specified font and it really hinges on what the end-user's console/terminal font settings are.

I've implemented a bash script to grab the number of columns and lines the user's terminal is currently sized at during start-up and write those values to a file that my Java code then reads.

Is there a way through Java, or with a game start-up script, to have a certain font used by the end-user's terminal before the game loads? Has anyone handled this sort of problem with their own text-based game? Is it maybe best to just inform the end-user that a certain kind of font (monospaced, sans serif) is preferred to have the best gaming experience?

Comment: Do you need to display the text on the terminal from which your application is launched?  Most text adventures do not do this.  Instead they create their own display window, fully under their control, on which they display the game text.  This also supports the case where there is no controlling terminal at all, such as may be the case when the game is launched from a GUI.

Comment: I was wondering about that... Using `exec` and passing in the game script so that it would use its own terminal instance; I found that the user-selected font is still what would be used as default.

I've tested with a few other text-based adventures out there in the wild and they're displayed with whatever the user-selected font is as well, so it's just best, I think, to design the game with a monospaced font and inform whomever might play to temporarily switch their custom font over.

Comment: If the windowing system is X based, you can launch a terminal passing in configuration parameters to force the launched terminal to have the font you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy actually. What you should do is create your own console window with a JTextPane or a JTextArea and create redirect the print stream to that. Here's an example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConsoleWindow printWindow = new ConsoleWindow().fixPosition();
        PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(printWindow.jTextArea));
        System.setOut(stream);
        System.setErr(stream);


        System.out.println("This is a custom console window.");
    }
}

class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}

class ConsoleWindow {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);

    ConsoleWindow() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            setupFrame();
            setupPanels();
            setupTextArea();
            setupScrolling();
            makeVisible();
        }).start();
    }

    private void setupFrame() {
        frame.setSize(854, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setLayout(null);
    }

    private void setupPanels() {
        panel.setSize(panel.getParent().getSize());
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        panel.add(jScrollPane);
    }

    private void setupTextArea() {
        jTextArea.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 20)); // TERMINAL FONT
        jTextArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // TERMINAL COLOR
        jTextArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN); // TEXT COLOR
    }

    private void setupScrolling() {
    }

    private void makeVisible() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    ConsoleWindow fixPosition() {
        jScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(0);
        jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will of course need to ditch the use of a Scanner and use actionPerformed methods instead for grabbing your input. If you need help with this, i'd be glad to help.

Comment: I like this suggestion, I hadn't considered taking advantage of some of the actual GUI capabilities of Java. Thanks :)